# Adding tasks to a List<Task> executes them making Task.WhenAll() redundant

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have a bunch of async web queries that I need to run at application startup. Why in this example both tasks execute even if I comment out this line?

```
//await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

It seems that there is no difference whether I use Task.WhenAll() or not. How come?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Execute();
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static async void Execute()
{
    Func<Task> Task1 = (async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Task 1 completed.");
    });

    var tasks = new List<Task> { Task1(), Task2() };

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private static async Task Task2()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Task 2 completed.");
}
```

Comment: @Will It doesn't block the thread it returns a task that completes once all the other task complete, which in turn could be used to block the thread.

Comment: Calling Task1(), Task2() will execute the tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `WhenAll` does is construct a new `Task` that will be completed when all of the tasks provided to it have completed (and propagating errors/cancellation/results as appropriate).  It doesn't *start* anything, or *do* anything.  Any changes to the behavior of your program have to do with what you do with the `Task` it returns, that's all.

The methods start executing when you call them, which is done here:

```
var tasks = new List<Task> { Task1(), Task2() };
```

Note that *if* your method returned a `Task`, then without the `await Task.WhenAll` that `Task` would be completed as soon as you finished *starting* the tasks, rather than when they finished running, and the returned task wouldn't be faulted if either of the tasks error out or are cancelled.  With the `WhenAll`, *if* your `Execute` method returned a task, it wouldn't finish until both of those tasks had finished, and would propagate their errors.

But since you used an `async void` method, which you need to be very careful about using (it's *usually* wrong to write such a method, as is the case here) there's no way for the caller of the method to even observe the difference between you using `WhenAll` or not.